# NumPy: Logarithm with base n

Tags: python, math, numpy, logarithm

From the [numpy documentation on logarithms](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html#exponents-and-logarithms), I have found functions to take the logarithm with base [*e*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html#numpy.log), [2](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log2.html#numpy.log2), and [10](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html#numpy.log10):

```py
import numpy as np
np.log(np.e**3) #3.0
np.log2(2**3)   #3.0
np.log10(10**3) #3.0
```

However, how do I take the logarithm with base *n* (e.g. 42) in numpy?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

If you have numpy 1.23 or later, you can use [np.emath.logn](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.emath.logn.html):

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([74088, 3111696])  # = [42^3, 42^4]
base = 42
exponent = np.emath.logn(base, array)  # = [3, 4]
```

---

*If your version of numpy is older:*

To get the logarithm with a custom base using [`math.log`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log):

```
import math
number = 74088  # = 42^3
base = 42
exponent = math.log(number, base)  # = 3
```

To get the logarithm with a custom base using [`numpy.log`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html):

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([74088, 3111696])  # = [42^3, 42^4]
base = 42
exponent = np.log(array) / np.log(base)  # = [3, 4]
```

Which uses the logarithm [base change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) rule:

[image: \log_b(x)=\log_c(x)/\log_c(b)]

Comment: I cant understand why base isn't a parameter in numpy's log... I'm always coming back here...

Comment: "When will I ever use this?" -Student

Comment: @polvoazul Same, plus I'm confused why there's a totally different positional parameter, `out`, so when naively switching `math.log(number, base)` to `np.log(array, base)`, you get confusing errors like `TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment` or `TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType`. Apparently all ufuncs have the `out` parameter, but if it were keyword-only, it'd be so much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's base n logarithm function is [np.emath.logn](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.emath.logn.html).

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([74088, 3111696])      # = [42^3, 42^4]
base = 42
np.emath.logn(base, arr)              # array([3., 4.])

np.emath.logn(14, 14**3)              # 3.0
```

Note that unlike `math.log`, **the base is the first argument**. Also, unlike `math.log`, it can handle negative numbers (returns a complex number).