# Python & Numpy : How can I produce a value of Logarithm with base = a and argument = b, AKA log_a (b)?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I'm trying to produce a calculator for `Logarithms` with Base a and Argument b using `NumPy`.

I have read the documentation for `NumPy` but it looks so confusing.

How do we calculate `Log_a (b)`  using `NumPy`?

Thank you

Comment: You can use base-change rule, following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169297/numpy-logarithm-with-base-n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is basic maths. You can use the approach of `log(value)/log(base)` For more information, this cheatsheet seems to cover it. https://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/Algebra%20leaflets/mc-logs3-2009-1.pdf

I hope this helps

Comment: Also here: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Properties_from_the_definition_of_a_logarithm