# Skew array toward maximum value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an array

```
A = np.arange(1,11)
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

and I want to apply a skew to it to shift values towards the maximum, whilst keeping the upper and lower limits the same, to achieve something like this:

```
B = myfunc(A)
B = np.array([1,5,7.5,8.7,9.2,9.5,9.75,9.85,9.95,10])
```

[image]

How would I best go about this?

Note, the values chosen are random values from my head to give an idea of the general idea :)

Thanks

Comment: What are the constraints on the input values? Always positive? Non infinite? Monotonic?

Comment: Alwyas positive, non infinite, that last word means nothing to be in a numerical sense sorry (after Googling I believe yes monotonic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function which skews the values using a logarithmic or exponential function. In your case, you want a transformation that gets closer to the maximum value while preserving the original scale.

Here's an approach using a logarithmic function to achieve a skewed transformation:

```
import numpy as np

def myfunc(arr):
    min_val = arr.min()
    max_val = arr.max()
    range_val = max_val - min_val
    
    # Apply a logarithmic function to skew the values
    log_base = 10  # Adjust this base for desired skew
    shifted = arr - min_val + 1  # Shift values to avoid log(0)
    log_values = np.log(shifted) / np.log(log_base)
    
    # Scale the log-transformed values back to the original range
    result = (log_values / log_values.max()) * range_val + min_val
    
    return result

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

B = myfunc(A)
print(B)
```

This function `myfunc` uses a logarithmic transformation to skew the values towards the maximum while preserving the upper and lower limits. The `log_base` variable is used to control the extent of the skew.

This code shifts the values to avoid taking the logarithm of zero, applies the logarithmic transformation, normalizes the values between 0 and 1, and scales them back to the original range.

You can adjust the log_base value to achieve different degrees of skew towards the maximum while ensuring the upper and lower limits remain the same.

[image]

Comment: Awesome thankyou. Just so you are aware, currently adjusting the log_base value does not affect the skew in any way.

Comment: my bad, dividing by the maximum of the logarithmic values will rescale them to a range between 0 and 1, effectively normalizing them. I'll fix that and update the answer.

Comment: FYI, numpy supports log with arbitrary base (fairly new): `log_values = np.emath.logn(log_base, shifted)`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75553178/19123103).